# Why do people cite the ability to "define module boundaries" as an advantage of OSGI?

Tags: osgi

Don't the default Java access modifiers (public, protected, private) already define boundaries for how classes can be accessed. Why are these modifiers not sufficient? Why is OSGI's way of "defining moudle boundaries" better than this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the java access modifier's define a classes boundaries and to some extent a package's boundaries but a module is larger than a single class or package. You may want to see http://www.slideshare.net/bjhargrave/why-osgi which explains the progression of encapsulation through classes and onto modules.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**

In a modularized system it is very important to separate API from implementation where only API is exported. You cannot do that based on class modifiers. Other very important part of OSGi is the versioning of packages. You have to assign version only to those packages that are exported.

**Long answer**

A more prcise answer to this question is available at the following wiki post that was written by Neil Bartlett: http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Export_Only_APIs

**Similar question**

Why do we need object-orientation when functions are already available in structured languages? Are not the functions used to separate logical units of an algorithm?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I still don't get this part: "It is very important to separate API from implementation where only API is exported. You cannot do that based on class modifiers." Didn't APIs exist before OSGI? Can't you create an API class that is modified with *public*, and make this class instantiate and call a separate "implementation" class that is modified with *protected* (or leave as default) so that the implementation is not visible to other classes outside of the package?

Comment: If your implementation is logically separated to multiple packages, you cannot hide the classes from outside. Also there would be an issue with versioning without exported packages. Before OSGi, packages did not have a version. Only exported packages need to have a version and a bundle is not wired to another bundles but to packages based on their versions.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about it a little bit, and realized that there are certain privacy restrictions that OSGI's export mechanism can impose that plain old Java access modifiers cannot. See the diagrams below.
[image]
[image]

Notice how in Plain Old Java, a public class is visible (indicated by a green arrow) to all classes no matter what. In OSGI, a public class is visible to all classes (including classes in another bundle) ONLY if it is part of an exported package.

Note:The "protected classes" in the diagram are really just classes without any modifier (since there is no "protected" modifier for classes, just for fields and methods)

Edit: I'm adding this relevant quote from here: http://njbartlett.name/files/osgibook_preview_20091217.pdf

> "A public class is visible to every class in every other package; a default access
>   class is only available to other classes within the same package.
>   There is something missing here. The above access modifiers relate to visibility
>   across packages, but the unit of deployment in Java is not a package, it is a
>   JAR file. Most JAR files offering non-trivial APIs contain more than one
>   package (HttpClient has eight), and generally the classes within the JAR need
>   to have access to the classes in other packages of the same JAR. Unfortunately
>   that means we must make most of our classes public, because that is the only
>   access modifier which makes classes visible across package boundaries.
>   As a consequence, all those classes declared public are accessible to clients
>   outside the JAR as well. Therefore the whole JAR is effectively public API,
>   even the parts that we would prefer to keep hidden. This is another symptom
>   of the lack of any runtime representation for JAR files."